# RegEx for string of groups delimited by " and ,

Tags: python, regex

I have a string of the type:

```
"04/15/2013","A lot of text: numbers 123,412","3,123.99","-","1,123,123,99"
```

What would be a regular expression to parse it so that I get each of the comma separated strings (the ones delimited by ") for further parsing?

I'm interested on using python's regex module, but if a better solution is given, it'll be fine

Comment: Wouldn't this call more for the `csv` module? Or simply `split('","')`?

Comment: @Hyperboreus I think not, since there are also commas inside some of the values: "3,123.99" for instance

Comment: Can there be `","` inside a literal? I doubt it. If any it could be `",\"`.

Comment: This isn't regular. It's really awkward to parse with (extended) regexps. `csv` module will deal with the quoted commas and the escaped quotes.

Comment: Guess I have to review the csv module docs then :) let me check!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `csv` module:

```
import csv

text = '"04/15/2013","A lot of text: numbers 123,412","3,123.99","-","1,123,123,99"'
result = next(csv.reader([text]))
# ['04/15/2013', 'A lot of text: numbers 123,412', '3,123.99', '-', '1,123,123,99']
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the reader handles quotes and field delimiters as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Just split it:

```
>>> s = '"04/15/2013","A lot of text: numbers 123,412","3,123.99","-","1,123,123,99"'
>>> s[1:-1].split('","')
['04/15/2013', 'A lot of text: numbers 123,412', '3,123.99', '-', '1,123,123,99']
```

Your argument that the tokens can contain commata is of no importance, as no token can contain `","`.

Comment: Values may end with `\",`. Whatever generates this may decide there's no need to quote integers.

Comment: If it is CSV, this holds. But OP asked explicitly about splitting "groups delimited by " and ,".

Comment: genius! haven't thought about it! Yes, in fact, that's what I want. And yes, it is CSV, but I wasn't thinking straight when thinking about regexes XD

Comment: @JavierNovoaC. Then nevertheless you should stick to the `csv` module, in order to handle correctly quotes, escapes, delimiters, continuations, etc, etc.

Answer (score -1):

None of the other responses, while correct, use regular expressions. The way this would be done using regex

```
import re 
arrayOfStrings = re.split(r',', stringToBeSplit)
```